# Sends a request-body in a GET

Tags: rest, curl, request, axios, http-get

I'm trying to get data from API
I used curl to send a request body

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" exemple.com/api/filter -XGET -d '{"param1": "aa"}'
```

and it's works, I've a data result but using axios it doesn't work

```
axios.get("exemple.com/api/filter", {data: {"param1": "aa"}}).then(response => {
        return response.data;
      }).catch(err => {
        alert(err);
        console.log(err);
      })
```

There are any way to have an equivalent  of curl -xGET  to Axios ?

Thanks!

Comment: "A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics" -- there's no particular reason so assume that any given general-purpose HTTP component will do something useful with one.

Answer (score 0):

If this is run on the browser it will not work since:

> The body argument provides the request body, if any, and is ignored if the request method is GET or HEAD.

https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method

However, if you running this on node engine it should work.

You should think about switching to `axios.post` to send json data to your api instead of get. If you are trying to get data then use query params `axios.get(..., {params: {"param1": "aa"}})`.